# Will C++20 modules change the anatomy of static and shared libraries?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-modules

Traditionally, C++ libraries are made of a header file + the implementation compiled in a binary file (`.a`, `.so`, `.dylib`, `.dll`, ...). The header file is `#include`d in the source code and the binary part is linked to the final executable.

Will modules from C++20 change such layout? If so, will operating systems have to upgrade the way they distribute their core libraries, e.g. the Standard Library in Linux or other core dlls in Windows?

Comment: Well, I haven't studied the latest draft specs, but one thing that's always going to continue to be necessary is *backward compatibility.*  The mountains of existing software still have to be able to be compiled, even if a language introduces a "better way to do it."  The `.h` file strategy *is* primitive, but it can never go away.

Comment: IIUC modules are designed with the ability for the compiler to generate a sort of "module definition file" when compiled. Which to me seems very reminiscent of a pre-compiled header. So I don't think this duality is going anywhere. Only the compiler switches are likely to change.

Comment: As of C++ 20 threre are no standard library modules in the spec, this is [C++23 target](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0592r4.html): `Now that Modules are in C++20, C++23 should ship with a specification of how the functionality of the standard library is exposed as modules.`

Comment: modules are pretty much just pure compiled headers so will pretty much just be a straight swap for the existing headers, i don't think anything else will change

Comment: Binary should still be there, but indeed, providing header and/or module definition files might vary (and as module definition format has not been standardized, header seems the more portable way)

Comment: Libraries are basically just object files. Those will still be compiled and distributed as before and get picked up by the linker (dynamic or not). An open question is therefore only if there is a replacement for headers. @AlanBirtles PCH are only for compilation, not for distribution. You'll never find PCH in libxyz-dev (Debian example) packages. You will still need a format that allows your code to find declared library symbols. Right now those are the pure plaintext header files. We will see if module interface units are a valid replacement (backwards compatability put aside for now)

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica GCC creates CMI (compiled module interface) files during compilation. Is that what you meant? However, such a format is implementation dependent and cannot be used for distribution. I am not aware of a compiler phase which generates distributable files (except from the plaintext module interface units).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely. Modules are a very different type of representing library code to users than conventional header/libraries. The main advantage of a module is to have it parsed to the level of the **abstract syntax tree (AST)** by the compiler. This only happens once per module -- in contrary to every time you include a particular header file. Thus, one possibility for speedup is to convert very frequent header files into modules and save a lot of compiler time in not re-compiling to AST many times, but just once. AST also works perfectly fine for templates ... it is a generic and complete description of the C++ language.

But this is currently also the main "drawback": ASTs are absolutely compiler dependent. There is no stability between vendors, systems, or even compiler versions. So distributing ASTs makes no sense, at least in the current toolchain environment.

Thus, in my understanding, modules are not easily a replacement for common header/libraries. They are a ideal replacement for lightweight (best header-only) and potentially highly templated code to be included many times in typical programs. Many libraries, foremost the standard libraries, are like this. But there are also many libraries of different design (small API+heavy binary backend). For those, I guess, we will have to continue to use include/libraries as before. But, C++ is backward compatible, so mixing modules with includes is no problem at all.

Also, modules can just wrap include files (e.g. with an API). This is probably not a very powerful usage of modules, but may lead to a more uniform programming pattern. In this case, you would still need to link your "so" or "dylib" or whatever library to the resulting code.

Thus, I believe the future at some point will distribute both, some C++ modules, but also conventional headers+libraries. Modules by themselves can be split into many files (only the "exported" symbols are visible to users). Modules will likely follow very different design guidelines than headers. It very likely will not be any advantage to have "one class per module", but rather "a whole bunch of logically connected code per module".